# Why isn't my position updating in ref.current.position

Tags: reactjs, three.js, ref, react-three-fiber

I am trying to change the camera position in my r3f scene based on a mesh position. I am also using r3f/cannon for physics and ref positioning. Whenever i try and retrieve the position of my body, the ref thinks it hasnt changed and i just get the initial set position. Why can't i retrieve the updated position? Here is a snippet of the ref and useFrame

```js
  const [ref, api] = useSphere(() => ({ args: [5,10,10], mass: 1, position: [0, 15, 0], material: { friction: 10}, ...props }))
  
  useFrame(({clock}) => {
    console.log(ref.current.position)
  })
```

It only ever logs the initial position, even if the object is moving around

Answer (score 1):

This is because cannon is not updating the `position` of the object.
The object position is updated through a `matrix` transform.

you can use the api to get the updated position:

```js
const [ref, api] = use...(...)
const pos = useRef([0, 0, 0])
useEffect(() => api.position.subscribe(v => pos.current = v), [])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! I did end up digging more into the react-three-cannon library and found this out. This is the correct answer though so thanks for getting to this :)

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to access the position will be ref.current.position

Comment: Thanks but this was an edit after trying everything. ref.current.position only gives out the initial position. I have edited the post to reflect that

Comment: is your ref attached to the mesh tag for the sphere ? like in 12 of this example https://codesandbox.io/s/g1s88

Comment: of course it is...